# Size of overflow:hidden div with position:absolute one inside

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have html code like this:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
         some content
    </div>
    <div>
        content with unknown height
    </div>
</div>
```

Outer block has `overflow:hidden`, because it should be resized according to resizing of the second inner block. But this way the first inner block is cropped if the second one (and so the outer one) is not big enought.

How can I get it not cropped (or another way to make outer div resized)?

Comment: Without a specified dimensions `overflow:hidden;` should not crop anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question:

`overflow: hidden;` hides the scrollbars and keeps the element at its specified dimensions. Either you can change it to `overflow: auto;` or just remove it as that is the default state.

Comment: And also it changes the size of outer block if it is not specified. `overflow:auto` adds scrollbars to outer block if absolute positioned inner block is larger.